# Scanning in IPv6

Tags: nmap

I just came across this statement.

> Scanning IPv6 network, however, offers a large number of hosts in a subnet if an attacker can compromise one host in the subnet; attacker can probe the **all host link local multicast address.**

I do understand that IPv6 have a larger subnet with about 128bits of addressing schemes and that's the reason scanning of network becomes a tedious job by using traditional scanning methods. But what exactly does the `all host link local multicast` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IPv6 there are different kinds of addresses:

- Unicast adddress is the unique address of a node.
- Anycast address: Usually an IP prefix that is advertised from multiple locations. It relays in the network the decision of which location to use based in routing protocol costs.
- Multicast adddress. An address that represents a group of nodes on the network. IPv6 uses them mainly to send messages to multiple nodes once at a time avoiding to use broadcast addresses because they reach every node on the network. An example is the NDP (Neighbour Discovery Protocol) that it's used as a replacement of IPv4 ARP.

IPv6 has defined a lot of different multicast addresses. The *link local* multicast adddress is `ff02::1`.

If from a compromised host an attacker send a ping to that address, the ping reachs all the hosts in the network.

Something like this in Windows:

```
ping - 6 ff02::1
```

or this in Linux

```
ping6 -I eth0 ff02::1
```

will receive responses from all the hosts, something like these:

```
64 bytes from fe80::215:5dff:fe01:2909: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
64 bytes from fe80::215:5dff:fe01:2911: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.57 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from fe80::20f:d3ff:fe59:cae3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=9.08 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from fe80::215:5dff:fe60:152: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=17.4 ms (DUP!)
```

And then, it's easy to gather the IPv6 adddress of all hosts in the network and the attacker can start to attack each one of them.

As the responses are *link-local* addresses if the attacker wants to test how many of them are reachable from outside the network, they have to be converted to *global* address replacing the initial `fe80:` with the IPv6 subnet prefix.

---

There are other IPv6 multicast addresses that can be useful for an attacker.  The following list shows the officially defined IPv6 multicast addresses.

```
Address     Description

ff02::1     All nodes on the local network segment
ff02::2     All routers on the local network segment
ff02::5     OSPFv3 All SPF routers
ff02::6     OSPFv3 All DR routers
ff02::8     IS-IS for IPv6 routers
ff02::9     RIP routers
ff02::a     EIGRP routers
ff02::d     PIM routers
ff02::16    MLDv2 reports
ff02::1:2   All DHCP servers and relay agents on the local network segment 
ff02::1:3   All LLMNR hosts on the local network segment
ff05::1:3   All DHCP servers on the local network site
ff0x::c     Simple Service Discovery Protocol
ff0x::fb    Multicast DNS
ff0x::101   Network Time Protocol
ff0x::108   Network Information Service
ff0x::181   Precision Time Protocol (PTP) version 2 messages except peer delay measurement
ff02::6b    Precision Time Protocol (PTP) version 2 peer delay measurement messages
ff0x::114   Experimental
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but what does link local multicast actually mean? And I have researched a bit and found out that there are other casts as well like unicast, any cast, broadcast etc... what are these? What is link local and what is meant by all host link local multicast ?

Comment: @M.S.P I addded some information about it in the answer.